# How can I get only the properties that are custom attributes on the model itself?

Tags: ember.js

I have a custom model attr (similar to what ships with ember-data)

```
var attr = function() {
    var value = '';
    return function(key, val) {
        if (arguments.length === 2) {
            value = val;
        }
        return value;
    }.property()
};
```

I annotate my model properties with it like so

```
var Foo = Ember.Object.extend({
    firstName: attr()
});
```

What I'm looking for is a way to get "only" these attrs when I loop through the "keys" on this instance (example -in my rollback method I want to reset each of these - but no other keys should be reset)

```
var Foo = Ember.Object.extend({
    firstName: attr(),
    rollback: function() {
        for(var key in this){
            this.set(key, "some value here");
        }
    }
});
```

It it possible to make this attr special in some way so I can loop over only those attribues on the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with solution to your problem. Inside `attr()` method add `meta` to computed property. Seems like it was designed for cases like this one:

> In some cases, you may want to annotate computed properties with additional metadata about how they function or what values they operate on.
>   ([API Documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_metaForProperty))

So, `attr()` method:

```
var attr = function() {
  var value = '';
  return function(key, val) {
    if (arguments.length === 2) {
      value = val;
    }
    return value;
  }.property().meta({ isCustomAttr: true });
};
```

Object definition:

```
var Foo = Ember.Object.extend({
    firstName: attr(),
    rollback: function() {
      Foo.eachComputedProperty(function (item) {
        if(Foo.metaForProperty(item).isCustomAttr)         {
          console.log('This property was defined using custom attr() method and its key is: ' + item);
        }
      });
    }
});
```

[Working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sawimaqiwu/3/edit) Outputs:

> "This property was defined using custom attr() method and its key is: firstName"

I believe it is trully the Ember way.

Comment: Nice! I was looking over something like this in ember-data itself and you nailed it! https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/attributes.js#L53

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a hash of these 'special' properties and iterate through that instead?

Comment: that was a thought - just looking for something that would be more hands free /automated. I'm planning to extract a simple isDirty/rollback base class (something like DS.Model) long(er) term

Comment: Is this a question, comment or an answer?